# Does this grow exponentially?

Tags: limits

I have a very basic question.

Does $c^{-n}\to 0$ exponentially?

Dont know exactly what this means resp. how to show it.

I think $c\neq 1$, otherwise this does not convergerge to 0 at all

Comment: If $0<c<1$ then $c^{-n}\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Based on your question, perhaps this observation would help: for $c>0$ we have $c^{-n} = e^{-n\ln(c)}$.

Comment: It decays exponentially. It doesn't grow exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't GROW if it goes to $0$. If $0<c<1$ then $c^{-n}$ GROWS exponentially. If $c=1$, $c^{-n}$ is constant, if $c>1$, $c^{-n}$ decays exponentially.

Comment: Whats with $c<0$? And how can I see/ prove that this is exponential rapidly?

Comment: @mathfemi If $c<0$ then it is going to oscillate between positive and negative, so it will not really diverge consistently.

Comment: This is a definition. A sequence grows exponentially if $s_n=kc^n$ for some $c>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Growing exponentially is a question of $\color{blue}{relative\ speed}$. There  is a wide range of speeds, and $\color{red}{saying}$ that some sequence is $\color{blue}{growing \ exponentially}$ $\color{red}{is}$ locating its speed among the others possible speeds!

From lower to higher speeds one can mention $$\log n,\ n^{1/2}, n, n^{2}, n^{3}, \dot , c^{ n}, ( c>1).$$